# QOpenGLWidget: retrieving window handle for 3rdparty library

Tags: c++, qt, opencascade

I'm creating an application, which interacts with OpenGL via *QOpenGL** classes. The graphics is shown through a *QOpenGLWidget*, which is placed in a UI-form.

Now, there is a library for CAD purposes ([Open CASCADE](https://www.opencascade.com)), an OpenGL interface of which requires a handle to the render window. The question is: can I somehow say the library to render everything to the mentioned widget?

In other words, is there a way to interpret the widget as a native, probably,  platform-specific (HWND here) window, so that the library renders its own stuff exactly there?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into [`qOpenGLWidget->context()->screen()->handle()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#handle)?

Comment: @metal, *handle()* returns a pointer to *QPlatformScreen*. A bit confused in fetching the handle from it

Comment: See how that type is defined on your platform.

Comment: @metal, I found the class [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qplatformscreen.h.html#QPlatformScreen), and I couldn't find anything related to handles in there (although I could've missed something).

Comment: Blind leading the blind, but see the [private implementation](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qopenglcontext_p.h.html) of the context object. It has a `void*` handle. Check how it's used and if you can manage to get access to it.

Comment: @metal, calling off. *QOpenGLWidget::winId()* actually works, see the answer below for details

Answer (score 1):

**QOpenGLWidget** is not the same thing as **QGLWidget**.

The classical approach for embedding OCCT 3D viewer, which you can find in Qt IESample coming with OCCT, creates QWidget with unique window handle flag, takes this window handle and ask OCCT to take care about OpenGL context creation for this window. This is most straightforward, robust and portable way with one limitation - Qt will not be able drawing semitransparent widgets on top of this QWidget. This is not a limitation of OCCT, but rather limitation of Qt Widgets design.

**QOpenGLWidget** was intended to solve this limitation by allowing to mix custom OpenGL rendering and normal widgets. The integration of external OpenGL graphics engine, however, became more complicated and fragile. It is not very helpful stealing winId() from QOpenGLWidget, as rendering content is expected to be drawn not into window itself, but rather into OpenGL framebufer object (FBO), created by QOpenGLWidget - see **QOpenGLWidget::defaultFramebufferObject()** property.

External renderer is expected to render into this FBO for proper composition of Qt widgets. Luckily, OCCT is flexible enough to allow such integration. Unluckily, such integration requires some knowledge of OpenGL, as well as its usage by Qt and OCCT.
For that, you need to ask OCCT wrapping OpenGL context already created by Qt (for that **V3d_View::SetWindow()** provides an optional argument of type *Aspect_RenderingContext*, which corresponds to **HGLRC** on Windows and can be fetched using **wglGetCurrentContext()** within rendering thread) as well as FBO created by QOpenGLWidget (for that, OCCT provides **OpenGl_FrameBuffer::InitWrapper()** and **OpenGl_Context::SetDefaultFrameBuffer()** methods, as well as **OpenGl_Caps::buffersNoSwap** flag to leave window buffer swapping management to Qt).

OCCT doesn't come yet with a sample using **QOpenGLWidget**, but you can find also **qt/AndroidQt** sample implementing similar thing for embedding OCCT 3D Viewer into **QtQuick** application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on that? I've tried your suggestions using `QOpenGLWidget` without using an OS-specific `getContext`, but the context provided by the widget instead. I'm failing to use that in `V3d_View::SetWindow()` as it cannot be cast to `Aspect_RenderingContext`.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I found that method *QOpenGLWidget::winId()* returns the correct handle. It's been found out only now, because the rendered scene disappeared immediately, leaving a black picture instead. However, when the viewport is resized, the scene returns back (and disappears again, though). Looks like Open CASCADE has problems with Qt 5 OpenGL implementation, since QGLWidget didn't have such problems, as far as I know.

Comment: Switching to *QGLWidget* and using *paintEvent()* for drawing instead of *paintGL()* did the trick. Disappointing that I will have to use obsolete API...

Comment: [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) state that `winId()` should be avoided because it possibly leads to rendering glitches, which explains the problems you were having. Not a great input but I just wanted to drop this here. I am also looking for the answer to the same question and will post it as an answer if I happen to find anything.

Comment: @Deniz, there really were glitches: screen went black when any kind of dialog appeared. But I managed to avoid it by running the program on a discrete video card instead of an integrated one.